# Dealing with customized local source files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Our team of 4 currently uses svn, but I am testing out Mercurial. We code mostly in C++ and C# on .net. I have installed TortoiseHg, and use hgsubversion to push/pull against the existing svn repo. Other developers on the team will remain on svn for now.

I tend to have a few source files that I have customized (butchered would be a better term) in some specific way that I don't want to push to other developers. But I do want these custom changes compiled into my version of the project. The ratio of normal files to customized files is about 100:1

What is the best way to deal with these butchered files in mercurial? I could simply uncheck butchered files during commits, but eventually, I will forget this step. I have taken a brief look at shelving and ignoring.

Ignoring doesn't seem right, because these are tracked files. I do want to pull changes to butchered files from others. Shelving was close, but it removes the butchered code from my working copy, so that isn't correct either.

I can't be the only code butcher out there. Let me know how you deal with this. Git users, we are happy to hear from you too, we haven't entirely committed to using hg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're files most everyone will be modifying (per developer database account info, etc.) the right way to do it is by tracking a `xxxxx.sample` file.  For example have the build script use  `local-database.config` which is in the `.hgignore` and provide a `local-database.config.sample` file in the repository.  You can either include "copy the sample to the actual" in your instructions or have the build script do it automatically if the actual doesn't already exist.  We have our config do a include of settings.local if and only if it exists, and allow it to override main settings.  Then no one needs a local config, but it can be optionally used to alter anything w/o a risk of committing it.

If they're files that only you will be modifying the best way is to learn Mercurial queues.  Then you can `pop` that changeset with the you-only changes, push to central repo, and then apply it again for your builds.  There are various extensions that do similar things (`shelve` for example), but mq is preferable because you can version the overlay you're popping and applying.

Comment: We have one db config file that fits the sample model, but my question pertains to source files I have tweaked in ways that won't be repeated by others. At first, I rolled my eyes at your MQ suggestion. But I am starting to get it. MQ solves something else I need (temporarily shelving modifications that aren't ready for commit, so I can do a pull from svn).

Comment: MQ isn't easy, and it's slowly being replaced by something really amazing but if you've got a lot of scattered changes to many files that you can't extract out into separate included files it's definitely the way to go for now.